# how to save mouse event (instance) in .txt file and then open it as intance again

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have an onclick function that takes self and event (event is of type instance ) so can i save this event in xml or .txt file so i can open it back again by browse button as an event instance and give it back to this add_point function

```
   def add_point(self, event):
    if self.radioButton.isChecked() == True:
        if ((event.xdata)**2 + (event.ydata)**2)**0.5 < 1 and event.ydata >0 :
            print(type(event))
            print (event)

            z = event.xdata + event.ydata * 1j


            self.xy.append([event.xdata, event.ydata])
            self.xy.append([event.xdata, -event.ydata])
            self.zero.append(z)
            print (self.zero)
            self.update()
```

def browse(self):

```
    filepath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Single File', "C:\Users\Hanna Nabil\Documents",'*.txt')
    f= str(filepath)
    file =open(filepath ,'r')
    connect = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect
    connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)
    self.draw_cid = connect('draw_event', self.grab_background)
    with file:
        text= file.read()

        #self.add_point(c)
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think do you want to save `event` instance and reload it later. You could use `pickle` package.

```
import pickle

'''
    To store the instance
'''

path = 'path where do you want to store the event'

output = open(path,'wb')    # Open a file to store the instance binary (your event)

pickle.dump(self.binario, output)    # Dumping the instance binary to the file

output.close()    # Closing the file        


'''
    To load the instance
'''    

input = open(path,'rb')    # Open the file    

event = pickle.load(input)    # Loading the instance binary

input.close()    # Closing the file
```

The `event` variable is what you stored previously, and you can use it to your purpose.

The general purpose of `pickle`package is to store binary files like instances or classes and reload it later in your same code or in another project.

Comment: Thanks Marco 
i've used cPickle before but it gives me almost the same error when i use the method your wrote above 


  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.py", line 71, in _reduce_ex
    state = base(self)
TypeError: the sip.wrapper type cannot be instantiated or sub-classed

Comment: The message `TypeError: the sip.wrapper type cannot be instantiated or sub-classed` says that you can't instantiate the object with type `sip.wrapper`, which surely refers to a component of your GUI. How are you using the code or instantiate your object? It seems an error of `sip`package, which is a component of PyQT. I expect this helps you :)

Comment: yes exactly um trying to save the instance event which comes from connect('button_press_event', self.on_click) 
the main object for my code is to draw zero and poles on a unit circle when user click.. i need to save some drawn points and make user able to restore them by browse button

Comment: MPL MouseEvent: xy=(77,184) xydata=(-0.996450831025,0.0242382271468) button=1 dblclick=False inaxes=Axes(0.177465,0.1;0.67007x0.8)  
________________________________
that's what appear to me when i print event

Comment: I have seen that you used `cPickle` package instead of `pickle`. And the error you wrote says _TypeError: the sip.wrapper type cannot be instantiated or sub-classed_. I think that is because of you imported `cPickle`. Check the following link to know about the differences: [Should I use Pickle or cPickle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111980/should-i-use-pickle-or-cpickle) If doesn't runs, answers this comment and I'll check what can be happening. Regards :)

Comment: I've seen this link [In PyQt, how can I save the items and selected item in a combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666756/in-pyqt-how-can-i-save-the-items-and-selected-item-in-a-combobox) in which the best answer explains that `pickle` can't save PyQT instances. It suggests to retrieve the instance data and save it separately. I suggest you to create your own class to store the `event` attributes you want and save it with `pickle`. When you reopen your app, you can reload the class and reinstance `event` with the attributes of the class that you loaded.